# Sorting vector of pairs with int and Points

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std-pair

I have some problem with sorting my vectors.I want to sort my vectors acording to first element wchich is Number.Can someone explain me what I doing wrong and what this 2 errors means?

I try sort this with compare function and without it and nothing works.

```
struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool compare(int a,int b){
     return a < b;
}

int main()
{
int N,Number,x,y;

cin >> N;
vector<pair<int,Point>> p;
for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++){
    cin >> Number >> x >> y;
    pair<int,Point> pom = {Number,{x,y}};
    p.push_back(pom);
    }
//    sort(p.begin(),p.end());
//    sort(p.begin().p.end(),compare);
return 0;
}
```

I've got two errors but I don't know what means:
1.no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const Point' and 'const Point')
 || (!(__y.first < __x.first) && __x.second < __y.second); }
2.body of constexpr function 'constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = Point]' not a return-statement
       || (!(__y.first < __x.first) && __x.second < __y.second); }
                                                                 ^
                                                  ^

Comment: You don't need a comparator for `int`s, this is already provided in the language. What compiler doesn't know is how to compare two instances of `Point` class. Or a comparator for `std::pair<int, Point>`, if you would prefer to use it only in the `std::sort` function (rather than providing an `operator<(Point, Point)` for everyone to use)

Comment: Points do not implement comparison operators since there is no definition of how to compare Points.

Comment: Also, you probably want your compare operator to return an int, not a boolean. It's not an Equals operation or a less Than operation. It's < 0 if a < b, == 0 if a==b, and > 0 if a > b.

Comment: @JosephLarson If this function is to be used in `std::sort`, then it is expected to return `true` if element `a` should go before element `b`, `false` otherwise.

Comment: Ah. I should have checked.

Comment: @JosephLarson I see you're most active in Java tag, confusion is understandable :)

Comment: Returned to C++ last year after nearly 20 years in the Java world. I should have checked before I commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparator for `int`s is useless and probably Undefined Behaviour. Compiler knows how to compare two integers, it's part of the language. It also knows how to compare two instances of `std::pair`. What it doesn't know, is how to compare two instances of `Point` class, which is defined by you.

Basically, you have two options:

**1. Provide `operator<` for `Point`**

This will let you compare two points easily in any situation later on:

```
bool operator<(const Point& p1, const Point& p2) {
    if (p1.x == p2.x) 
    {
        return p1.y < p2.y;
    }
    return p1.x < p2.x;
}
```

**2. Provide an in-place comparator for `std::sort`**
This is a quick solution if you only need to compare stuff for sorting purposes.

```
std::sort(p.begin(), p.end(), [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) {
    //whatever logic it takes to compare two std::pair<int, Point>
});
```

*Note:* Generic lambda (with `const auto&` as arguments) is a C++14 feature. Lambdas themselves are C++11 feature.

Choice between above depends on the usage. If you just need to sort a vector, of if the logic for sorting is unusual, go for `std::sort` comparator. If you want to always compare two `Point`s in the same way, go for operator overloading.